# Bandpass before EEMD- selecting IMF outside band pass range

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, bandpass, adaptive-algorithms, decomposition

I have a vibration signal of 25.6 kHz where I first perform band pass filtering (7000 Hz, 9000 Hz) and then perform Empirical Mode Decomposition (EEMD).

I then want to select the IMF where the kurtosis value is maximised (I'm looking for fault impulses in a gearbox).

IMFs:
[image]
As you can see, the max kurtosis value is in IMF 5 (there are some more IMFs I did not include).

**My question:**

If I select IMF 5 and perform a FFT, I see that the signals are in the 2000 Hz range. How is this possible, given that I already band passed at (7000 Hz, 9000 Hz)? Is it incorrect to use this IMF for further processing then?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Filter implementation using [butter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html) from SciPy

```
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data, axis=0)
    return y
```

Comment: IMF is a kind of decomposition so it should not generate new signals. How did you design your band pass filter?? Is the sampling frequency appropriate taken into account? Is the attenuation gain low enough to filtering out the noise in 2000Hz? Can you provide sample code/data ?

Comment: Updated the question with some code.